# laravel passport 11.8 unsupported_grant_type

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport

I installed a new `Laravel v10.x` project I also installed `laravel/passport v11.8` for api authentication but I can't do with this it gives me `unsupported_grant_type`, I set all this up by whatever the documentation says but nothing happens, what will be the reason for this.? anyone facing this issue in newly installed `laravel/passport` package. how can I solve this please help me, I'm stuck here a long time

I searched many solution but nothing is work for me.

#### config/auth.php

inside guardes array.

```php
'api' => [
   'driver' => 'passport',
   'provider' => 'users',
   'hash' => false,
],
```

#### In AuthServiceProvider

```php
public function boot(): void
{
   Passport::tokensExpireIn(now()->addDays(15));
   Passport::refreshTokensExpireIn(now()->addDays(30));
   Passport::personalAccessTokensExpireIn(now()->addMonths(6));
}
```

#### In my controller

```php
public function getTokenAndRefreshToken($request, $client)
{
    $request->request->add([
       'grant_type' => 'password',
       'client_id' => $client->id,
       'client_secret' => $client->secret,
       'username' => $request->email,
       'password' => $request->password,
       'scope' => '*',
    ]);

    $instance = Route::dispatch(
        $request->create(
           '/oauth/token', 'post'
        )
    );

    return json_decode($instance->getContent());
}
```

What is wrong I can't understand please help me.

Comment: So ugly code. You using oauth totally wrong. May be use sanctum?

Comment: yeh so ugly, what will be nice plz tell me, sanctum is not solved my problem so I have to use a passport, have you any solution?